# HTML code not rendered correctly on outlook 2010

Tags: html, outlook

I am able to render an html code with tables correctly on the browser, but when received on outlook 2010, the tables structure goes missing. Below is my code.
Is it because of any html tag that outlook is not able to render? Please help

```
    <div style="color: black; font-family: Calibri;"> <img src="../images/Survey.png">
<br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Customer Establishment Feedback Survey</p>Hi [CONTACT_NAME],
<br>
<br>We would appreciate if you could complete the <b>Establishment Feedback Survey</b> below. This is in relation to your experience of your [PRODUCT] setup.
<br>
<br>
<table width="970" height="547" border="y">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Communication Provider Name</p>
            </td>
            <td width="409.5">
                <p>[CONTACT_NAME]</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>CE Delivery Manager(s) engaged with</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>[USERNAME]</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Date Survey Completed</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Product(s) established for</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>[PRODUCT]</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>How would you rate your overall level of satisfaction with the end to end set up your new product ?&nbsp;</p>
                <p>(on a scale of 1 to 10, with 1 being lowest and 10 being highest)</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>Please add comments if applicable</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>What worked well with the set-up of your new product ?</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp;</b>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>What did not work well with the set-up of your new product ?</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Please add any other comments about your set-up experience that you would like to bring to our attention</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;Thank You</p>
<br> Regards,
<br> [USERNAME]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change `border="y"` to `border="1"` in the parent `table` tag (or increase the value to increase size of border)